# Feynman diagram with fixed and on-shell internal lines

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Say I've got two scalar fields $\pi$ and $\phi$, where $M_\phi > 2M_\pi$, and the interaction $$\frac{\lambda}{2}\pi^2\phi$$

At order $\lambda^3$ the $\phi\rightarrow\pi\pi$ decay gets a correction from the following diagram

[image]

I'm confused as to how the internal $\phi$ line can be treated since its momentum is fixed and on-shell and thus inserting a propagator just gives 1/0.